# How to use Converter to bind TextAlignment to string property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Simply i want to make converter to bind TextAlignment option enum to string property .. i found converter is the solution after long searching but i'm still can't do specific one for my case .. any help ? 
I use this code

**EnumtoStringConverter.cs**

```
    class EnumtoStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var returnValue = value as string;

        if (returnValue == "Start")
            return "Start";

        else if (returnValue == "Center")
            return "Center";

        else if (returnValue == "End")
            return "End";

        return returnValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

        }
    }
```

**Xaml**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <controls:ExtendedButton HorizontalContentAlignment="{Binding HoriRLLR}" Margin="20,0,0,0" Image="house.png"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" Text="{translator:Translate HomeSpacing}"></controls:ExtendedButton>

                    </StackLayout>
```

HoriRLLR is the string property which i want to bind

I know i should write code in convert method but i don't know What do I miss? and if i'm in right way or not ?

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095689/set-background-color-depending-on-data-bound-value

Comment: good but when i bind the property nothing changed :/

Comment: in your `ExtendedButton` class what's the type of the Bindable property `HorizontalContentAlignment` ?

Comment: @apineda enum and it's Xlabs componant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this you can make enum property and bind direct to this property Use TextAlignment for this 
your code will be like

```
Private Enum alignment{get;set;}
```

and in constructor

```
alignment = Textalignment.End
```

in xaml 
horizontaloption bind in aignment property

Comment: Thank u very much it helped me